# Read and write model properties from a lambda expression argument

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a settings service class that loads settings from a file or if they are already loaded, just returns the value from the local settings object.  I want to access the settings via set and get methods with a lambda expression parameter.

I defined a private GetSettings method:

```
private async Task<T> GetSetting<T>(Func<Settings, T> property, T defaultValue)
{
    if (_settings != null) return property(_settings);

    await TryGetSettingsFromFile();

    return _settings != null ? property(_settings) : defaultValue;
}
```

So I can get a value like this:

```
public async Task<int> GetAppStartUpTimes()
{
    return await GetSetting(s => s.AppStartUpTimes, 0);
}
```

This works as expected but I couldn't figure out how to make a SetSetting method.  I want to do something like this:

```
public async Task SetAppStartUpTimes(int value)
{
    await SetSetting(s => s.AppStartUpTimes, value);
}
```

For the SetSetting method I've tried:

```
private async Task SetSetting<T>(Expression<Func<Settings, T>> property, T newValue)
{
    var propertyInfo = (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    propertyInfo.SetValue(_settings, newValue);
}
```

but propertyInfo is always null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `.Member` could be either `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo`.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works fine, if AppStartUpTimes is a property. Is it a property or a filed of the Settings class?

Comment: @MaksimSimkin that's indeed the problem.  It was not a property but a field. Now it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and works if you set Properties, but you will get a null if you try to cast `FieldInfo` to `PropertyInfo`, if you have both Fields and Properties in your settings class you could change your code this way:

```
private static async Task SetSetting<T>(Expression<Func<Settings, T>> property, T newValue)
{
   var propertyInfo = (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(_settings, newValue);
    }
    else
    {
        var fieldInfo = (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member as FieldInfo;
        fieldInfo.SetValue(_settings, newValue);
    }
}
```

If you have just fields, you should only change cast:

```
private static async Task SetSetting<T>(Expression<Func<Settings, T>> property, T newValue)
{
        var fieldInfo = (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member as FieldInfo;
        fieldInfo.SetValue(_settings, newValue);
}
```